# Why my gdb prompt shows wrong after I change its color

Tags: linux, gdb, prompt

I change my gdb prompt's color by writing `set prompt \033[1;33m(gdb) \033[0m` into `.gdbinit`file. And I change my gdb prompt's color sucessfully.

But I find that my long command with my parameters will overwrite my prompt after I input a long command without going to newline. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: if your gdb has python scripting enabled, look at [@matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31019968/2554472) to see how to do this using the `set extended-prompt` command - it's a better solution.

Gdb manages command input by using the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) package. The way to tell readline that a character sequence in a prompt string doesn't actually move the cursor when output to the screen is to surround it with the markers `RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE` (currently `'\001'` in readline's C header file) and `RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE` (currently `'\002'`).

Bash has a portable way of expressing this: when it sees `"\["` and `"\]"` in the prompt variable, it will convert them to `RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE` and `RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE`. Bash does this while it's processing various other escape sequences such as `\w` to include the current working directory.

Gdb's `set prompt` command doesn't support `"\["` and `"\]"`, but you can put the octal escapes `\001` and `\002` in your `set prompt` string (subject to change if readline's authors ever choose to use a different set of markers).

```
set prompt \001\033[1;33m\002(gdb) \001\033[0m\002
```

Answer (score 1):

gdb has a command: [set extended-prompt](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Prompt.html#Prompt) that accepts escape sequences described in the [gdb.prompt python module](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/gdb_002eprompt.html#gdb_002eprompt). which includes the \[ and \] bashism's for wrapping characters that do not contribute to the prompts length.  This of course requires a python enabled gdb to work though.